# How to draw a burette using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to give my students some assignments where they need to read several burette readings in order to perform calculations based on titration results. How can I achieve this using tikz?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could use something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149247/tikz-fill-a-glass-tube-with-red-color as a starting point

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274139/drawing-two-identical-tubes-to-illustrate-a-math-problem

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533061/drawing-a-section-of-a-burette

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 2):

run with `lualatex`:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}%       For L3
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pst-labo}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\pstDosage
\pstDosage[glassType=becher,phmetre=true] 
\pstDosage[niveauReactifBurette=10,niveauLiquide1=60,
    aspectLiquide1=Champagne,glassType=flacon,agitateurMagnetique=false] 
\pstDosage[glassType=erlen,burette=false]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's impressive that pst-labo can do this, but this seems to be every except what OP was looking for.